# How to add one hot vectors?

Tags: machine-learning, one-hot-encoding

I have a few one hot vectors(more than 2) of size 48 each. How can I add them? Is there any specific method or simple arithmetic addition? If arithmetic addition then how should I handle the carry bit?

I know this may be a very basic question but I am new to the field of Artificial Intelligence and need help.

Comment: What would be the purpose for adding one-hot vectors?

Comment: @KonstantinosKokos I am trying to replicate the work of a paper where the authors have added the one hot vectors. They added few vectors of size 48 each and got the ouput vector of the same size. I couldn't understand how they did it.

Comment: Let me rephrase - what would be the motivation of the authors to do this? Adding one-hot vector sounds completely counter-intuitive since they are simply basis vectors encoding distinct categorical objects. What are you trying to achieve by adding them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well adding one hot vector isn't a usual practice. It is exclusively task centric. I was dealing with timeseries data when posted this question.

Suppose you have three one hot vectors `[0,1,0,0]`, `[1,0,0,0]` and `[0,1,0,0]`. The addition process that I followed was to add these vectors in bit-wise fashion i.e `[0+1+0, 1+0+1, 0+0+0, 0+0+0]`. The resultant vector would be `[1,2,0,0]`.

However, the major concern (with very large numbers of vectors) is the case when the addition produces a carry. In such a case, one may simply treat the two (or three) digit number as one i.e. `[12,2,0,100]`.

PS: This is a highly data-centric approach. There may exists better proposals.

Answer (score 0):

One hot vectors are basically **vectors**. To the same summation applies to them ,which applies to normal vectors.

To add or subtract two vectors, add or subtract the corresponding components.

Let u=⟨u1,u2⟩ and v =⟨v1,v2⟩ be two vectors.
Then, the sum of u and v is the vector

u+v=⟨u1+v1,u2+v2⟩